# Inherit height from container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a wordpress site, and I want a sidebar to have the same height as the container.

Like this:

[image: How it should be]

However, some pages look like this:

[image: how it looks]

Here's the current css:

```
 #secondary .widget_nav_menu{
    background:url(xxxsbbg.png) repeat-y;

    width:270px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:-50px;
    padding-bottom:400px;
    padding-top:20px;

    }
    #savusumo{
    background:url(xxxsavusumo.png);
    height:341px;
    width:361px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left:-120px;
    }

#secondary .menu a{
color:white;
}
#secondary .menu{
list-style:none;
}
#secondary .menu .menu-item{


}
#secondary .sub-menu{
list-style:none;
}
.valittu{
width:100px;
background:red;
}
#secondary .menu-item{
margin:10px; 0px;
}
```

I've  tried `height:100%;` but it looks pretty much the same. And using inherit would inherit the height of div #secondary, and I need to inherit the height of #primary. Is it possible?

The sidebar:

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary" style="position:relative;">
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

                <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

                <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_register(); ?>
                        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>

            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>

            <div id="savusumo"></div>
        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-2-column-left-menu.htm

Comment: Can you edit your code so that it makes sense to us who don't have the slightest idea about what `savusumo` selector selects? ;-) Just try to rewrite it so that it is a minimal and concise example of the problem.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - You know, I don't know why I didn't think of this; have you considered implementing a grid system? like [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts) or [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)?

Comment: I don't actually know anything about grid systems. Neither about wordpress theming, so I'm just modifying the default theme.

Comment: I was look at the theming setup and I remember why I don't like messing with WP.

Comment: Yeah, it just wordpress is the easiest CMS for client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after your comment I'm assuming you're using the Twenty Eleven template, which is default when you install 3.4.2. So I looked at the template setup and figured out (in a very basic sense) you could do the following and use the `display: table` technique:

**Main Index Template (index.php)**

Move the `get_sidebar()` function from the bottom of this template to right below `get_header()` at the top:

```
...
get_header(); 

get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
```

What this does is "resolve" the layout problem. This template uses the `float` method, and the sidebar content is actually injected *after* the `content` area on the left. One of the reasons why I get annoyed by this technique, and also the root cause of you inability to stretch the sidebar.

**Header (header.php)**

Now look in this file, which contains the DOCTYPE, `html` and `main` element tags, and the `head` tag, which is what we're looking for. Copy and paste this into the indicated locaiton:

```
    wp_head(); // Find this and right after the close ?> tag...
?>
<style>
#page #main {
    display: table;
}
#page #main #secondary,
#page #main #primary {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
#page #main #primary {
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
#page #main #primary #content {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#page #main #secondary {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 0 30px;
    background-color: #cff; // <<< This right here demonstrates the full height
}
</style>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

And that's it! Well, actually, there's a number of places to check and figure out what needs to be done in the other templates (if anything). This at least shows you that it can work, you just have to manipulate the location of the `get_sidebar()` function and reset some of the CSS settings like `float: left`.

Here is the template above applied to a simple WP installation on my site:

http://jfcoder.com/wp/

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a copy of Twenty Eleven, so this is PERFECT for me!

Comment: But how about using the sidebar on left?

Comment: I mean, with your css and in your code, the sidebar is positioned on the right side of the content. I want it to be on the left?

Comment: Hmm. It shouldn't be on the right, it should be on the left. When you view it, it shows up on the right when you visit my link?

Comment: Yeah, it shouldn't be. But it's on right on my page? take a look at http://bit.ly/NXneCU (sorry for bitly, I don't want bots on the site before it's ready)

Comment: You forgot to move `get_sidebar()` up under `get_header()`. You have to rearrange that function so `#secondary` falls before `#primary` in page load.

Comment: Ok, not sure if I understood it fully, but here's the index.php http://pastebin.com/ABZTcEAN

Comment: Your PHP tags are getting munged; the top one isn't closed. [Here's mine](http://pastebin.com/mtGM1iEQ). What you have can't be right, though, since the physical location of `#secondary` is *after* `#primary`. Have you made sure to click the Update File button (after fixing the PHP tags)?

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using custom-sidebars plugin to create the submenus, but it should only give me a change to select which sidebar to use?

Comment: I noticed the PHP tag problems too, but I fixed them and edited the paste.

Comment: View source on my page and look at line 89. You'll see `<div id="main">`, immediately followed by `<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">`. Look at line 113 and you'll see `<div id="primary">`. So WP is injecting that `#secondary` sidebar element between `#main` and `#primary`. Look at your source code, though, the `#secondary` element is down at line 150, where it would have been in default. There's something else going on here. Is that link you gave in the bit.ly using the Index Template?

Comment: My link should be using the default template... I have modified the CSS and installed the plugin custom sidebars but I've no idea why it's like that.

Comment: Ok, for instance, **Sidebar Template Page Template (sidebar-page.php)** has the `get_sidebar()` down below. It's probably like that in several spots, so you'll need to review if you need to adjust those other templates.

Comment: It's the Page Template: `<body class="page page-id-88 page-template page-template-sidebar-page-php...`

Comment: However, I think you need to edit **Sidebar Template Page Template (sidebar-page.php)**.

Comment: So I need to move get_sidebar() on the top of primary div on every file? **EDIT** Moving the get_sidebar(); on that file moved the sidebar.

Comment: I think you need to review if you need to. You may not be using every template file, or you may not want to, just depends on your business needs.

Comment: Here's a Bootstrap WP theme that's free: [Roots Theme](http://www.rootstheme.com/). I'm sure you're too far into it on this project to change direction, but you might keep it under consideration in the future. Lots of good stuff there.

Comment: Hey, from Roots link: *Template markup is handled by `base.php` instead of being scattered across all template files like typical themes.* That means what we're monkeying with now wouldn't have been necessary.

Comment: So if I've been using the roots theme, this would have been easier?

Comment: You have to learn Bootstrap, which isn't hard but can be different, I suppose. But yeah, that's what they're claiming. This would have been a layout: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples (The middle one.)

Comment: Actually, the middle one is fluid, I converted mine to static because it looked just horrible on my phone.

Comment: You just take `-fluid` off the class name and it's no longer fluid. Here's a demo I did for another question: [Affix and Scrollspy Demo](http://jfcoder.com/boiler/test/affix.html).

Comment: But what do you mean with `you have to learn Bootstrap`? Is it still html, js, css and PHP?

Comment: It's all HTML, CSS and Javascript; no server-side, just template technique. It's hard to describe; I'd looked at it several times over a few months and was like, What is this about? I couldn't figure it out. So you just have to go through the docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ It's as much mentality. The plain markup/CSS stuff usually is pretty straight-forward, but that affix and scrollspy demo was a little more challenging.

Comment: Once you figure out what it looks like, you'll start seeing it all over the place; it's the *template de rigueur* right now. If you do a lot of layout and lightweight design work, yes it will.

Comment: Yeah, I will do a lot of design work. But I also code the system behind the scenes, like ajax form forms and so, this won't break anything? If I just keep the wordpress filters turned off?

Comment: The Roots theme I think you'd be ok as long as you work with it the way they prescribe (I'm not a WP developer, so I don't have much of a perspective). Try the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://www.initializr.com/) offline and try to do some layout work; as far as synthesizing advanced layout technique, it's eye opening. It's like a power-tool for people who do layout and backend presentation models for a living.

Comment: Here's a list of some of the other grid systems out there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615201/451969 And this guy's site has some good introduction to the techniques: http://www.thegridsystem.org/ Khoi Vinh is also a master web interface designer, his theories underpin a lot of what grid systems try to accomplish. He is/was the UI designer for the NY Times.

Comment: Okay, I'll think about this. So if I've understood correctly, Roots theme brings the bootstrap on wordpress, and I can modify it more easily than other wp themes?

Comment: Looking through the documentation, that's what it seems like. This is a WP Roots themed site: http://diveidc.com/ The elements of Bootstrap you can pull out immediately, and the grid design process gives you a definite design principal to organize your designs around. That's why I say, you have to learn the technique; it's different to what you're used to, but it's a really strong technique.

Comment: There's also [reasonably priced templates](https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes) and [free templates](http://bootswatch.com/). Note, I'm not affiliated with any of these sites, I just like to pass them along.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't like making sites with WP, but as some clients require a CMS, I just had to start making them. From now on, I'll make them with Bootstrap.

Comment: WP is alright, I've just never liked hacking into it; it seems jumbled up in the code to me. For what it does though (publish content), it does a pretty good job. I think Time.com is a WP site, for instance. That's kinda like, wha?

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: table;`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>

.container{ display: table; overflow: hidden; }
.left, .right { display: table-cell; }
```

**Edit:**

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3k95/) with jQuery and NO display: table;

Comment: I don't use tables on my design. There must be a better solution.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - `display: table` is not the same as semantic table layouts; essentially, it just gives whatever elements the same display characteristics. I consider this approach more better than crufty `float` methods, with far less frowny-face problems like `clear`ing.

Comment: As this would be impossible to merge with wordpress, I still can't use this.

Comment: Dipaks, if I might suggest, `<aside class="left">` and `<section class="right">` and `<!doctype html>`?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen check the Fiddle I posted :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish if the OP is using HTML5 then Yes! he should choose aside and section

Comment: @Dipaks wordpress is using html5, but I'm wondering how I'm going to set this up on wordpress. I set #page{display:table;}, #secondary{đisplay:table-cell;} and #primary{display:table-cell;} but it only messed up my page width.

Comment: And I added the script you provided.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - Do you have a link where we can see the actual markup and css?

Comment: I'll just think that I'll forget that, it's too hard to get working on wordpress.

Comment: WordPress and CSS don't disturb each other. You can use `display:table-cell` until your eyes bleed, and WordPress wouldn't care. There is a `style.css` file that you need to edit.

Comment: @amn it just broke the layout on the default theme.

Comment: That's not WordPress fault, that's what CSS does - it breaks layouts (and builds other layouts). The answer above is seriously correct one. You just need to locate your containers and style them. WordPress is a PHP application that simplifies authoring generated markup, your layout breaking has nothing to do with it. Good luck ;)